# Trigger compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino

I want to write c++ code for Arduino (actually a extension of the HardwareSerial part).
The user can pass settings in his sketch like

```
Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1);
```

SERIAL_8N1 is a preprocessor constant. But some UARTs like one of the SAM8XE don't allow all options. This is why i wan't to trigger a compiler error if a user tries to use a invalid option. Because the code will run on a microcontroller i don't have the chance to raise exceptions or something like that.

Is there a way to trigger compiler errors in c++ with a useful help text like "invalid UART options"?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to drop a compile error if the user writes SERIAL_8N1 in the code?
If so, I'd define a preprocessor macro which inserts invalid code, like

```
#define   SERIAL_8N1     this will drop an error
```

or you can play with the #error preprocessor directive

Comment: No, not if the user uses this option but if he uses it with the wrong UART. The real problem is that the user decides which option he will use in his sketch which means at runtime, so a preprocessor based error doesn't work in my opinion.

Comment: @Bouni Sounds like the Right Thing would be to not give the user the opportunity to select the wrong options.

Comment: @molbdnilo The problem is that i want to do the changes on something that is already out there. The Arduino authors want as less changes to the well known functions as possible. So i think that changing the whole system of mode selection is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boost to through static_assertions on compile time for this.

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( condition );
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( condition, "Not supported" );
```

Please check the following link for more detailed information: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

-Kim

Comment: On a microcontroller you usually want to avoid anything that is not _really_ needed because of the very small memory of the MC.

Comment: I know, but we used this macro ( you can just get the code from the library isolated ) also on our micorcontrollers. Of course it is not a good idea to use the whole library.